# EMFILE: too many open files (lazyFs.open)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, centos7

We have a React app builded using webpack. When we build our app we get about 1500 chunks with size of approximately 1-600 Kb. This build is published on a server running on CentOS 7 using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). Then we run a set of similar Selenium tests which basically just do login-logout to our website with redirection to other React components. All components are implemented using lazy loading. After some time our app crashes with this exception:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/project_name/dist/npm.core-js~36af4842.30b32b47.chunk.js'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:115:12)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

Here is our webpack-prod config:

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const TerserJSPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
        minimize: true,
        runtimeChunk: {
            name: entrypoint => `runtimechunk~${entrypoint.name}`
        },
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "initial",
            **minSize: 5000,
            maxSize: 10000,**
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
                default: false, // disable the built-in groups, default & vendors (vendors is overwritten below)
                reactDom: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]react-dom[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendor.react-dom",
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 20
                },
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name(module) {
                        // получает имя, то есть node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                        // или node_modules/packageName
                        const packageName = module.context.match(
                            /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/
                        )[1];

                        // имена npm-пакетов можно, не опасаясь проблем, использовать
                        // в URL, но некоторые серверы не любят символы наподобие @
                        return `npm.${packageName.replace("@", "")}`;
                    }
                },
                styles: {
                    name: 'styles',
                    test: /\.+(css)$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        }),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin()
    ]
});
```

Here is our webpack-common config:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const gracefulFs = require('graceful-fs');
gracefulFs.gracefulify(fs);
const path = require('path');
const SERVER_URL = require('./src/Global');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },

    entry: {
        'commons': ['string.prototype.startswith', 'react', 'react-dom'],
        polyfills: './src/polyfills.js',
        vendor: [
            'react',
            'redux',
            'lodash',
        ],
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$/,
                exclude: [/\.inline\.svg$/],
                use: ['url-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.inline\.svg$/,
                use: ['svg-react-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'public/', to: 'img/' }
        ]),
    ],
    externals: {
        // global app config object
        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: SERVER_URL
        }),
    }
};
```

What we already tried:
1) Set ulimit -n 65536. Also tried setting to 2048 and 10000 - everytime the exception raises after some period of time. The more the value we set the longer it takes to raise an exception
2) Played with splitChunks.minSize and splitChunks.maxSize values: set them to bigger values and got less chunks with bigger size - the outcome is always the same

How can we fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got any solution?